# Historical Rolling Daily sum

Tags: sql, loops, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table of consisting of Dates and the amount of revenue recorded for that day going back for about 12 years.  What I would like to do with this data is create a new table with Dates and prior 7-day revenue numbers.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Below is an example of what my source table and what my results would need to look like....

Source Table..

```
DATE       |   Revenue
12/31/2013 |   200
12/30/2013 |   300
12/29/2013 |   400
12/28/2013 |   100
12/27/2013 |   200
12/26/2013 |   150
12/25/2013 |   350
12/24/2013 |   450
12/23/2013 |   200
12/22/2013 |   300
12/21/2013 |   100
12/20/2013 |   300
```

Resulting Table...

```
DATE       |   7Dayrev
12/31/2013 |    1700 
12/30/2013 |    1950
12/29/2013 |    1850
12/28/2013 |    1750
12/27/2013 |    1750
12/26/2013 |    1850
ETC......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via correlated subquery:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT a.[DATE], a.Revenue, (SELECT SUM(b.Revenue)
                             FROM cte b
                             WHERE b.RN BETWEEN a.RN-6 AND a.RN) as Rev_7Day
FROM   cte a
ORDER BY a.RN DESC
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6008a/9/0)

Comment: Worked great.  Thank you so much!  I had been spinning my wheels on this for an embarassing amount of time...